# segmentation fault : transmission-gtk & transmission-qt in linux mint

Tags: segmentation-fault, transmission

When I run `transmission-gtk` on my Linux Mint, the window is shown as usual but suddenly it crashes. I tried `transmission-gtk` on terminal and the output was `Segmentation fault`. I didn't update or upgrade the system before this happened, but I did run `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove` once.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure transmission-gtk
```

And, if that doesn't help, completely remove it and reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get purge transmission-gtk && sudo apt-get install transmission-gtk
```

This could also be caused by something in your user's settings. Try renaming transmission's configuration directory:

```
mv ~/.config/transmission/ ~/.config/transmission.old
```

Comment: one of the torrent files is the reason. i put back all the `transmission old/torrents` files to new. then it crashed again. i deleted all and tried just a random torrent file. then transmission works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. After debugging it in IRC channel #transmission (thanks to xn0r!), we found it to be a bug in miniupnp: https://github.com/miniupnp/miniupnp/commit/3a87aa2f10bd7f1408e1849bdb59c41dd63a9fe9